# ruby on rails - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) when using 'form'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Showing `app/views/frontend/get_months.html.erb` where line #1 raised:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= render :partial => "months", :locals => {:form => form} %>
RAILS_ROOT: /rails_workcopy/er_spending_report
```

My `get_month.html.erb` has only one line of code.
if i use `<%= form.select(...) %>`, the error still occurs...
anyone can show me how to use render partial function?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is most likely coming from the partial itself since the code you posted here seems fine. Post its code here if you want more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (assuming you're passing the form through a block in form_for:

```
<%= render 'months', :f => form %>
```

Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html your render partial syntax is correct.

If there's only one line in get_month.html.erb I would wonder from where you get the local variable "form" is coming from. Maybe it should be @form?

Also keep in mind that the partial you want to render needs to start with an underscore. So in your example you need a file _months.html.erb